# Made game on Pygame. Any way to export to Facebook or Android?

Tags: android, facebook, pygame

I have a made a simple tile-based game in PyGame. Are there any ways through which I can make these games available on Facebook and/or android without recoding in Java or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android i would take a look at this[Pygame Android](http://pygame.renpy.org/) i haven't actually done it but i've seen it done it might take a little work from there you can put it in you're android device or if you have a developers account for the Google play store you can sell it i believe

i don't know if pygame can be put into Facebook because i think it has to be a flash game but you can take a look at [Pyjs](http://pyjs.org/) and you can but entire python scripts into a browser so id take a look at that

Good Luck!!

Comment: The pygame subset for android or pgs4a on pygame.renpy.org worked. I managed to port my pygame script to a functional apk within two days.